# Browser Errors "Error on page." - mainly IE, but page renders OK. Proper approach

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

My page is rendering as expected, but I am getting the infamous "Error on page." in IE8 in the bottom lower left corner.

Can anyone share with me their perspective on the credibility of such "warnings"? Is it worthing of debugging.

If Chrome or FF don't show any "warnings" and its only IE this truly does not surprise me.

```
The error is generated from the modalbox script and is: Message:
'this.focusableElements.length' is null or not an object
Line: 439
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://thedomainnameiamusing/js/okonet-modalbox-0d30559/modalbox.js
```

Just looking for some other perspectives on the approach I should take on this all..

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to access an object that turns out to be null is not a good sign.  If this code is going into production, I would fix it.  That may mean doing an if (thing == null) and then setting it to 0 if it is, or it may mean removing the offending line altogether.  439 lines is a long source file, and if Chrome and FF are not raising any warnings at all, I'm guessing the JS file contains chunks of code that are never actually executed.

Probably time for some cleanup (think of the poor guy who has to modify this code when you're done - even if that's you).